# Upgrading Liferay from 6.0.6 to 6.1.0 lost the portlets from pages

Tags: liferay-6

I upgrade from liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0.6 , it was successfully done without any error left; but when I upgrade from 6.0.6 to 6.1.0 GA1 portlets are removed from the pages as they were on pages in liferay 5.2.3 and in 6.0.6, I am asking for the liferay portlets like web content display etc.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Are you logged in the portal? Did you check in liferay database, in the layouts table, are there portlets specified for your layout (page)?

Comment: Thanks Martin , yes I logged in and there are all the data available in layout table. let me verify again the database as liferay has changed many things, may be I missed some.

Comment: Martin I verified there are portlet deployed for that page i.e for mainpage there are many portlets deployed in portletpreferences table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, here is the solution.
setting which portlet is placed on which page and on which layout-column is stored in the "layout_" table in the "typesettings" column.

there were layout missing, by deploying the required layout it works.

Thanks